# How can I setup USB OTG with a Raspberry Pi Zero W and an iPad over USB-C using Arch Linux?

Tags: usb, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, archlinux, ios

- Arch Linux
- systemd-networkd

I want my Raspberry Pi Zero W to show up as an ethernet device to my iPad. It is doable. [It's been proven to work](https://marcelwiget.blog/2018/12/02/tether-rpi-to-ipad-pro-via-ethernet-over-usb-c/).

The problem is in the details. After ensuring there is a usb0 device, I setup systemd-networkd. I know that the cable must support both power and data. I know that only the Power/Data USB port closer to the middle may be used. I know that the device supports UDC - USB Device Controller (which in turn supports the gadget mode (On the Go).

Requirements as I would guess:

- Fixed address for the Pi
- Pi is running a DHCP Server
- Multicast DNS is on

What steps am I missing that Raspbian Jessie is apparently doing automatically?

## /etc/systemd/network/10-usb0.network

```
[Match]
Name=usb0

[Network]
#DHCP=yes
DHCPServer=yes
DNS=8.8.8.8
Address=192.168.7.2/30
Gateway=192.168.7.1
MulticastDNS=yes

[DHCP]
#RouteMetric=10

[DHCPServer]
PoolSize=20
PoolOffset=3
DefaultLeaseTimeSec=500000
EmitDNS=yes
```

## networkctl

```
networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL      SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier          unmanaged
  2 usb0             gadget             no-carrier       configuring
  3 wlan0            wlan               routable         configured
```

Comment: did you perform all of the steps in the linked page?

Comment: @jsotola Yes. The fact that networkctl yields a usb0 device indicates that the steps were successful. The guide stops there and does not go into networking details, but using Arch Linux, one needs those details.